# How to enable fn and cmd keys shortcuts in zsh shell in OSX?

Tags: macos, zsh

After I installed zsh in OSX through macports, all kind of shortcuts like fn+right/left (which is alternative to END key, i've got a mini-apple keyboard), stops working.

Anybody knows how to enable all fn (and possibly cmd) shortcuts?

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your freaking great help superuser..com..

Answering myself:

enter `cat` command in terminal, and press shortcut which is lacking.. for example I was searching for fn+left arrow and fn+right arrow, then you will get binding to this shortcut, which I entered to ~/.zshrc then do `. ~/.zshrc`. in zsh man pages you'll find all the functions you can bind.

```
  bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line
  bindkey "^[[F" end-of-line
```